# Wrong data shown when searched

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a dataset of more than a million rows. I have integrated elasticsearch with Mysql using logstash.
When i type the following URL to fetch in postman,

http://localhost:9200/persondetails/Document/_search?q=*

i get the following:

```
{
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "persondetails",
            "_type": "Document",
            "_id": "%{idDocument}",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "iddocument": 514697,
                "@timestamp": "2017-08-31T05:18:46.916Z",
                "author": "vaibhav",
                "expiry_date": null,
                "@version": "1",
                "description": "ly that",
                "creation_date": null,
                "type": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "persondetails",
            "_type": "Document_count",
            "_id": "AV4o0J3OJ5ftvuhV7i0H",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "query": {
                    "term": {
                        "author": "rishav"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

it is wrong as the number of rows in my table is more than 1 million and this shows that total is only 2. I am unable to find what is the mistake here.

when i type http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
It shows this

1. health:yellow
2. status:open
3. index:persondetails
4. uuid:4FiGngZcQfS0Xvu6IeHIfg
5. pri:5
6. rep : 1
7. docs.count : 2
8. docs.deleted :1054
9. store.size : 125.4kb
10. pri.store.size :  125.4kb

This is my logstash.conf file

```
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/persondetails"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    jdbc_validate_connection => true
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/5.5.2/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM Document"
    type => "persondetails"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
    #protocol=>http
    index =>"persondetails"
    document_type => "Document"
    document_id => "%{idDocument}"
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    stdout{ codec => rubydebug}
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you see that the total is one in this response?

Comment: Sorry, its actually 2. you can see that the total is coming to 2 but there are 10lac rows in my table.

Comment: I see you have different mapping types. What do you get when running `GET http://localhost:9200/persondetails/_search?q=*` ?

Comment: i ran GET http://localhost:9200/persondetails/_search?q=* and got this result.

Comment: update your question with the result you get

Comment: I have edited it but the response is still the same. It shows the total as 2.

Comment: Then what about `GET http://localhost:9200/_search` ?

Comment: i have updated the health of the node as well. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: `docs.count: 2` means that you have only 2 documents in your index. So the problem lies more in how you stream data from MySQL via Logstash.

Comment: i ran GET http://localhost:9200/_search and got 3 in total now.

Comment: if you're supposed to have 10 lak rows and have only 3 docs, then something's wrong in your Logstash setup.

Comment: I have updated my logstash.conf file as well

Comment: The `stdout` output is not properly located (it should be at the same level as the `elasticsearch` one). this configuration should not run as it is.

Comment: So should i change the statement "stdout{ codec => rubydebug}" to "stdout{ codec => json}"? And also should i change the location of the logstash folder to the elasticsearch folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your result, it looks like there is an issue with your logstash configuration which is causing your document to be overwritten because the document_id is not getting generated, and effectively there is only one document in your index with document Id as "%{idDocument}"

See the following _source snippet from the result to the search query you provided:

```
"_source": {
            "iddocument": 514697,
            "@timestamp": "2017-08-31T05:18:46.916Z",
            "author": "vaibhav",
            "expiry_date": null,
            "@version": "1",
            "description": "ly that",
            "creation_date": null,
            "type": 1
}
```

Even looking at the small size of the index, it doesn't look like there are more documents. You should look at whether your jdbc input is providing the "idDocument" field.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I changed it from idDocument to iddocument in my conf file and it works. i dont know why this is happening as the the column name is idDocument in my table. Seems like jdbcinput is changing it to iddocument.

Comment: Hi @VaibhavSavala, You are welcome. You can use "lowercase_column_names => false" in the jdbc input input definitions to stop that from happening. The flag is outlined here -  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-lowercase_column_names . If this answers your question, please consider accepting it (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419)